# I am not able to write the css regular expression in selenium for a given line of code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

**The line of code for which i am writing the css regular expression is** `"<a href="https://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi" title="Already a user? Sign in" class="signin" xpath="1">Sign in</a>"`

**The css regular expression which i wrote is** -> `"driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//a[title*='Sign in']")).click();"`

**The syntax that i used was** "//tagName[attribute*='value']"

Additional information I was able to write the regular expression x path without error

```
"driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Sign in')]")).click();"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `//a[title*='Sign in']` to `a[title*='Sign in']`. For more details follow this [Link](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

the Syntax for CSS Selector using regular expression in selenium is

```
tagname[attribute* = 'value']
```

So change the locator as

```
a[title*='Sign in']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am really embarrassed that i made such a silly mistake thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

why are you writing a regular expression? when we work with web elements you need to inspect web elements and should work with locators like id, name, CSS selector, link text...etc

You just inspect and pick locators and use in your selenium